# Best way to expose OpenAPI specs to Client Services

Tags: git, openapi, code-generation, openapi-generator, service-discovery

I have a set of independent micro-services, all of whom follow an API-first design approach (The Controller interfaces and Models are generated at build time with OpenAPI-3 contract as single source of truth). And I want to expose these OpenAPI contracts to my clients(which will in-turn will generate client code from exposed OpenAPI contracts, A client can consume multiple downstream services). The OpenAPI contract is
version-controlled in the same git repository where micro-service code lives.

What's the best way expose these contracts, considering above scenario? And are there any open-source tools to support this requirement?

Here are few options that i explored:

1. Expose via git repository file link.(Cons: not suitable for private repositories)
2. Expose via a public Gist. (Cons: Separate maintenance of the gist on every update to the contract)
3. Export as a git sub-module. (Cons: Extra overhead of maintaining a separate repository for OpenAPI specs)
4. At the service build time, upload the OpenAPI contracts to a service-discovery. (Not sure what service-discovery tools support this feature of exposing OpenAPI specs as urls, any help is appreciated. Also one concern is that the service-discovery may become single point of failure).